# Работа с языковой системой в приложение создано на Python

Tags: python

Есть два языка на выбор: русский и английский. Как реализовать так чтобы например пользователь выбрал
русский язык весь интерфейс менялся на русский, если выберет английский то всё менялось на английский.
Как можно реализовать ? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: "Весь интерфейс" - это графическое приложение или консоль, где нужно цифру варианта выбрать что бы выполнилось какое либо действие?

Comment: А интерфейс-то в чём? Веб-приложение на Flask/Django/AIOHTTP, десктопное на Qt или ещё что?

Comment: графический интерфейс на PyQt5

Comment: Файлы локалей, например этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600848/pyqt-localization-translating-a-text-through-qpushbutton-w-use-of-po-file) может подкинуть идею.